# Apparently missing an exception

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

in my android app I have an AsyncTask which downloads photos from my server. If I get an exception (mainly for connection time out) I show the user a message. My problem is that my code works **MOST** of the times, (meaning there are times when I interrupt the WiFi connection that I get an exception shown in my logcat but the message won't appear so I ended it up  thinking that there might be an exception that I don't handle ) and I can't figure out the exact reason. I'll post the code run in my AsyncTask and the function that does the essential work. Hope you spot out something I'missing

```
        @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {               


    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject jsonObj = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
    Log.d("check1",url);
    try {

        list.addAll(processJsonData(jsonObj));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            onDownloadFailed(this);
            return "failed";
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            Log.e("Exception", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            onDownloadFailed(this);
            return "failed";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Exception", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            onDownloadFailed(this);
            return "failed";            
        }finally {
            jsonObj=null;
        }


        return "done"; 
    }
```

---

process JsonData is actually bigger that's the part for downloading the photos, the other part is about mapping string to an large Json File

```
  private ArrayList<Monument> processJsonData(JSONObject jsonObj) throws IOException, SocketException, JSONException{

            if(attachments!=null){
                int lengthSize;
                if(attachments.length()<3)
                    lengthSize=attachments.length();
                else
                    lengthSize=3;

                for(int j=0;j<lengthSize;++j){      

                            JSONObject atta = attachments.getJSONObject(j); 
                            JSONObject images = atta.optJSONObject(TAG_IMAGES); 
                            if(images!=null){
                                JSONObject medium = images.getJSONObject(TAG_MEDIUM);
                                String url_image = medium.getString(TAG_URL_IMAGE);                                 
                                String  id = atta.getString("id");

                                String filename =title.replace(" ","")+id+".nomedia";
                                File destination = new File(MyApplication.getPhotoStorage() ,filename);


                                    URL url = new URL (url_image);

                                    InputStream is = url.openStream();
                                    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destination);


                                    byte[] b = new byte[2048];
                                    int length;

                                    while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
                                        os.write(b, 0, length);
                                    }

                                    is.close();
                                    os.close();
                                    localPhotosUrl.add(destination.getAbsolutePath());

                            }

               }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: do you debug the code by turn off your wifi? Can please post your logcat

Comment: Try to use catch(Exception e). It will catch all the exceptions. Print the stacktrace then, and check it.

Comment: ok I think this was due to me trying to cancel a finished asyncTask. I thought that cancelling an AsyncTask that was already finished wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @libathos: Cancelling an async task that is already complete does not cause problems.

Comment: well that's what I thought, but now that I cancel it after I check if it's finished i don't get that exception anymore

Comment: @Dhaval - You should never catch `Exception` if your given an alternative. If you catch `Exception` then it will catch `RuntimeException`s, which is terrible practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API for [`InteruptedException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html) says the following;

> Thrown when a thread is waiting, sleeping, or otherwise occupied, and
>   the thread is interrupted, either before or during the activity.
>   Occasionally a method may wish to test whether the current thread has
>   been interrupted, and if so, to immediately throw this exception.

As described in the comments of the question, cancelling your `AsyncTask` only after checking that it has finished should prevent this issue.

Alternatively (but I would recommend against it), you could catch the `InteruptedException` in the method that cancels your `AsyncTask` to define your custom catch behavior there. Using `catch` to work around program logic flaws should only really be a last resort after reconsidering the logical flow of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could name the actual exception that is beeing thrown?
It might be a `RuntimeException` and therefore unchecked.

For further information about checked/unchecked exceptions see: [Oracle Docs - Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html%20Link)